# TimesTen 11.2.2 Hibernate 4 Dialect

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, timesten

I've been trying to use TimesTen 11.2.2.5 as a provider for Hibernate. In order to do so I had to download some [custom made Dialect](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/timesten/1122/quickstart/sample_code/j2ee_orm/config/hibernate3/TimesTenDialect1122.java) but then I realized that it is meant for [Hibernate 3.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/timesten/documentation/wp-timesten-appsrv-1122-1450939.pdf) (which is quite different from Hibernate 4.X).
Hibernate's packed dialects are for TimesTen 5 and are not really helpful...

What should I do in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

In timesten directory installation:

C:\TimesTen\tt1122_64\quickstart\sample_code\j2ee_orm\config\hibernate4

there is a README.TXT with the steps to follow for hibernate 4